# openshift express app serving static files

Tags: node.js, express, static, openshift

Noob here.  I'm trying to build an api server on Openshift using express.  I also want to be able to serve static files from the /static folder.  The problem is, I can't figure out how to set it up on Openshift.  I've tried everything I can think of.

I have 2 server files, the app setup which calls a router.js file for the routes.

app.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const http = require('http');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const env = process.env;
    const app = express();
    const router = require('./router');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const cors = require('cors');


    // DB Setup
    // default to a 'localhost' configuration:
    var connection_string = '127.0.0.1:27017/api:api';
    // if OPENSHIFT env variables are present, use the available connection info:
    if(env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
      connection_string = env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
      env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
      env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
      env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
      env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
    }
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + connection_string);


    // App Setup
    app.use(morgan('combined')); //logging middleware
    app.use(cors()); // allow cross origin requests
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*'}));  //read requests as json

 ----->  do I need to put something here ????

    router(app);


    // Server Setup
    const port = env.NODE_PORT || 3090;
    const ip = env.NODE_IP || 'localhost';
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(port, ip);
    console.log('Server listening on: ', port);
```

router.js

```
const Authentication = require('./controllers/authentication');
const passportService = require('./services/passport');
const passport = require('passport');
const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false});
const requireSignin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false});

module.exports = function(app) {

 app.post('/signup', Authentication.signup);
 app.post('/signin', requireSignin, Authentication.signin);

 app.get('/health', function (req, res, next ) {
      res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
 });

 ---->  and/or something here?
}
```

Everything works except serving static files.  Not sure if I need to put something in the app.js file as middleware, in the router file or both. Also not sure if I need to use Openshift environment variables?  Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: EDIT:  After I added the line: 
app.use(express.static('/static'));
to the app.js file, it DOES work locally but still not on Openshift.  

I really need some help, and since openshift is free, they are not very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

In express you can serve static files by adding the following to your `app.js` using [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static)

```
var path = require('path');

// put this before all of your routes
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
```

Comment: I tried this before without the path.join, now I've tried it again with the path.join as you have here.  It still returns 404 not found. When you say before all of your routes, do you mean in the router file?  Or in the app file where I have the arrow above?

Comment: Yes where you have the comment arrow

Comment: I tried it and I still get 404 not found.  I'm thinking it might have something to do with Openshift?  Maybe it's having trouble pointing to the right directory?  I can SEE the files are there, I just can't seem to serve them.

Comment: What is the actual path of your static directory? Is it actually `/static` under root? That's what the code i provided does.

Comment: Yes that's it.  Do I have to do anything in the router file ? As you can see I don't have a root route set up there.  Do I need to?

Comment: This might help -- this was the boilerplate that came with the Openshift setup.  It's uses httpserver not express.  Here's how they served static files:

Comment: let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  let url = req.url;
  if (url == '/') {
    url += 'index.html';
  }
  if (url == '/health') {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
  } else {
    fs.readFile('./static' + url, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
      } else {
        let ext = path.extname(url).slice(1);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentTypes[ext]);
        if (ext === 'html') {
          res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store');
        }
        res.end(data);